# How to get Parrot AR.Drone 2.0 fly? State Error occurred

Tags: ar.drone

I am trying to implement javadrone (AR.Drone Java API) in my project. However, it was occurred state changed error when I compile my java code and try to fly it. I was able to send command to AR.Drone and fly for the first time. After successfully take off for the first time,it won't take off again due to "state changed" error. I have no idea what went wrong in my code. Please help me out. Thanks! There are 3 files that are required in this project. My java file(arDroneFrame.java),NavData.java(from javadrone), and ARDrone.java(from javadrone).The The main java file: arDroneFrame.java. When I press the TakeOff button, it should make AR.Drone fly and land afterwards.

In my arDroneFrame.java,

```
private void jButtonTakeOffActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               
    com.codeminders.ardrone.ARDrone drone;

    try{           
        drone = new com.codeminders.ardrone.ARDrone();
        drone.connect();
        drone.clearEmergencySignal();

        // Wait until drone is ready
        drone.waitForReady(CONNECT_TIMEOUT);

        // do TRIM operation
        drone.trim();

        // Take off
        System.err.println("Taking off");
        drone.takeOff();

        // Fly a little :)
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        //Land
        System.err.println("Landing");
        drone.land();

        // Give it some time to land
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        // Disconnect from the done
        drone.disconnect();

    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(arDroneFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(arDroneFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(arDroneFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

In ARDrone.java, I had commented out some java coding.This is because only when I comment out those java code, it can only works. If I uncomment them, my program will be stuck there (no respond at all).

```
public void waitForReady(long how_long) throws IOException
{
    /*long since = System.currentTimeMillis();
    synchronized(state_mutex)
    {
        while(true)
        {
            if((System.currentTimeMillis() - since) >= how_long)
            {
                try
                {
                    disconnect();
                } catch(IOException e)
                {
                }
                // Timeout, too late
                throw new IOException("Timeout connecting to ARDrone");
            } else if(state == State.DEMO)
            {
                return; // OK! We are now connected
            } else if(state == State.ERROR || state == State.DISCONNECTED)
            {
                throw new IOException("Connection Error");
            }

            long p = Math.min(how_long - (System.currentTimeMillis() - since), how_long);
            if(p > 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    state_mutex.wait(p);
                } catch(InterruptedException e)
                {
                    // Ignore
                }
            }
        }
    }*/
    while(state == State.DEMO)
    {
        System.out.println("Changed to DEMO !");
                return; // OK! We are now connected
    }
}
```

Program Output:

```
126 [Thread-7] DEBUG ardrone.ARDrone - State changed from TAKING_OFF to ERROR   with exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.codeminders.ardrone.NavData$FlyingState.fromControlState(NavData.java:58)
at com.codeminders.ardrone.NavData.getFlyingState(NavData.java:622)
at com.codeminders.ardrone.ARDrone.navDataReceived(ARDrone.java:431)
at com.codeminders.ardrone.NavDataReader.run(NavDataReader.java:92)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: cleaned up formatting

Comment: Hi James, can I know what is the "cleaned up formatting" meaning? What should I do? Thanks !

Comment: At this point you don't need to do anything. Your error message were hard to read. Sometimes (but not always) error message need to be shown in a monospaced font. SO has several formatting options. Anything that is done to make your question easier to read is a good thing

Comment: Alrighr James. But do you have any idea why such errors occurred? Any error in my coding? It's weird. I can run the coding and make the drone fly sometimes. However,most of the time it shows me these errors and the ar drone refused to fly. Showing RED Leds lights.

Comment: Do you call `state_mutex.notify()` anywhere? If not, that may be why your program hangs when you uncomment the code. It looks like there's a problem happening when parsing the navdata; I wonder if maybe javadrone is out of date for your drone.